# TYPO3 7.6 - I can't break long titles in two lines

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

I'm importing a TYPO3 6.2 site into 7.6.

To avoid `<br/>` being converted to `&lt;br/&gt;` for more than 15 years or so I have used:

```
lib.stdheader.10.setCurrent.htmlSpecialChars = 0
```

It worked very well, but now with TYPO3 7.6 it doesn't work, or I'm doing something wrong.  I'm stuck.

I tried this old trick from Wiki.Resource (modification of Header.html in Fluid Styled Content):

```
<h1><f:link.typolink parameter="{link}"><f:format.raw>{header}</f:format.raw></f:link.typolink></h1>
```

and it works. However this is not a normal procedure.

Any suggestion?

Comment: This page states it is supported... https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/7.6/Functions/Htmlparser/Index.html?highlight=htmlspecialchars